# How to include comparator classes in UML diagram

Tags: uml

while studying for my software design exams something has come up and after looking everywhere I still can't find an answer so here it is.

What would be the correct way to show a comparator class used by the methods of another class to sort something?

Thanks in advance and sorry if i wasn't too specific since I'm new here.

The part of my code that uses comparator is something like this

```
public class Jukebox {

List<Song> jukebox= new ArrayList<>();

    public Song getSong(int index){
        return jukebox.get(index) ;
    }
    public List<Song> playTitulo(){
        Collections.sort(jukebox, new CompareTitle() );
        return jukebox;
    }
}
```

The Song class has several attributes such as tittle or duration and I have a different comparator class for each of them that looks like this

```
public class CompareTitle implements Comparator<Song>{
    @Override
    public int compare (Cancion c1, Cancion c2){
        return ( c1.getTitulo().compareToIgnoreCase(c2.getTitle()));
    }    
}
```

I think that much code should be enough to see what I'm doing since I don't want to bore you with an exercise from someone who's still learning but if you feel something is still missing tell me and I'll include it right away.

Comment: In lots of cases comparators are anonymous classes, could you show your code example? If you comparators not anonymous then it's just a class, should be no problem to display it even if it's inner.

Comment: Not sure if just by editing it's marked as updated so I'll leave this comment just in case

Answer (score 0):

Solved, it looks like what I was looking for was a `<<use>>` relationship.